# Chiptuning for a car with DPF (Diesel Particulate Filter) is a bad idea?

Tags: diesel, exhaust, electronic-control-module, diesel-particulate-filter

I know that it is possible to disable DPF (Diesel Particulate Filter). I'm wondering how bad it could be to leave DPF (Diesel Particulate Filter) functioning and add a chip to a car?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the acronym DPF, cars are an alphabet soup of acronyms and we can't read your mind. I'm thinking Differential Pressure Feedback?

Comment: Also remember, if this is an OBDII vehicle (and many OBDI cars as well), you won't be chip tuning anything. You don't have to replace anything. You use software to update the tune through the DLC port.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK it's common that people have a "DPF Delete" from their engine map which can improve performance at the cost of the vehicle no longer complying with emissions standards.  There seems to be no adverse long term effects on the vehicle over those with the DPF in place with the exception that they can consume clutch packs after fewer miles if driven hard (which relates more to the extra engine performance placing more strain on the part than the actual DPF removal).

There is a rolling road remap place behind my house and I regularly see all kinds of cars having a DPF delete carried out (curiously few Volkswagens though - as the DPF delete is effectively what they are in hot water for with the American authorities right now).

Comment: Just a note, removal of your DPF is illegal in the UK for public roads and will fail an MOT inspection. The standard procedure for inspecting if a diesel car still has its DPF is to lift it off the ground and see if there's a metal box where you expect to see a metal box, as such I cannot advise anyone to remove the DPF on a vehicle they intend to drive on UK public roads, but if they theoretically _were_ to remove such a device it would be best to ensure the device itself is actually hollowed-out and reattached to the vehicle, as to keep up the appearance that the vehicle still has a DPF.

Comment: Yes @JamesTrotter, completely agree.  The MOT regulations regarding emissions system removal have been effectively tightened up specifically because people were removing their DPF.